# Is it possible not to be contented in heaven?

Tags: heaven

Is it possible that after reaching heaven, you find yourself discontented? Like what if the things that make you happy are not there? Like your family, your wife and children. What if the people you love are in hell.

Is it possible to go to hell after deciding you don't like heaven?

Or is it that when we get to heaven we lose our own sense of happiness and become like robots that don't have a choice but to be happy with whatever is happening in there?

Do we still have free will?

What else would we do there if heaven is already perfect then there is nothing to improve.

Comment: Theres a lot going on here. Plus, as worded it's pretty close to a Truth question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of different questions here, and though they are all related, they could probably make multiple good questions. That being said, I'll try to answer them. One thing to note is that we know very little concrete facts about heaven, so most of this is simply inferred from Scripture.

> Is it possible that after reaching heaven, you find yourself discontented? Like what if the things that make you happy are not there?

This is a very popular question (just look at the number of [google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20can%20we%20be%20happy%20in%20heaven%20if%20our%20loved%20ones%20are%20not%20there&oq=how%20will%20we%20be%20happy%20in%20heaven%20if%20our&aqs=chrome.1.57j0.9409j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), but I would say that the answer is bound up in the answer to the first question of the [Westminister Shorter Catechism](http://www.reformed.org/documents/index.html?mainframe=http://www.reformed.org/documents/WSC_frames.html): `What is the chief end of man?`

The answer, `Man's Chief End is to glorify God and enjoy him forever` sums up the answer to your question nicely. If the purpose of our existence is to glorify God and Enjoy him forever (See [1 Cor. 10:31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2010:31&version=ESV), [Psalm 73:24-26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2073:24-26&version=ESV)), then we need nothing else in Heaven. Indeed, in heaven we will worship God, and as such our chief purpose will be fulfilled, therefore, we will be satisfied. Additionally, you could look at it from the perspective that since discontentment is sin (basis found in the Tenth commandment), and there is no sin in heaven, then there will be no discontentment in heaven. (for the broad answer of "What will we do in heaven", see [here](http://www.gotquestions.org/doing-in-Heaven.html)).

> Is it possible to go to hell after deciding you don't like heaven?

The [Westminster Larger Catechism](http://www.reformed.org/documents/wlc_w_proofs/), question 86 - `What is the communion in glory with Christ, which the members of the invisible church enjoy immediately after death?`, states:

> The communion in glory with Christ, which the members of the invisible church enjoy immediately after death, is, in that their souls are then made perfect in holiness, and received into the highest heavens, where they behold the face of God in light and glory, waiting for the full redemption of their bodies, which even in death continue united to Christ, and rest in their graves as in their beds, till at the last day they be again united to their souls. Whereas the souls of the wicked are at their death cast into hell, where they remain in torments and utter darkness, and their bodies kept in their graves, as in their prisons, till the resurrection and judgment of the great day.

The key thing to note here is that `their souls are then made perfect in holiness`. As I note later, if their souls are holy, why would they want to leave the presence of the supremely holy God?

The only people I think that *might* argue this would be those who argue you can lose your salvation, and I think even most of them would say that once you are in heaven, you are there to stay. But your question was not if you could get *kicked out* of heaven, rather if you could *voluntarily leave*. This is tied into your third question:

> Do we still have free will?

That depends on how you define free will. I am from a Calvinist theological background, and so I would say a resounding yes. Here's why, and I'll give an example to explain it:

Many find the concept of free will impossible to reconcile with the concept of predestination. But tied into this is the concept of Irresistible Grace. That is, when God calls you, it is so good you cannot resist the pull. Think of a wonderful chocolate cake (or some other delicious food). When you smell it, when it is sitting right in front of you, in a sense it is *irresistible* to you in that you will eat it because it is *so good*. God is so much better, so that when he offers himself to us, we are irresistibly drawn to him because of his infinite goodness. The same applies in heaven. We will have free will, but our eyes are opened to God's goodness, and as such we freely make the choice to worship him. As such, we would not *want* to leave heaven, and we would be completely content. *(if you reject the Calvinistic argument I make, the rest of the argument I believe still holds)*

Comment: I +1 for the first half. You tackled a Truth question well. The last half is just ok.

Comment: @fredsbend - what part are you referring to? The free will section? I'll admit, I found the wording difficult. Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: Well, you first quoted the Westminster Catechism, but then neglected it for the issues on going to hell after attaining heaven and on free will.

Comment: @fredsbend - good point, I could add something there

Comment: If it make you feel better. The question is closed and I only have one up vote to give (which apparently didn't go through this morning on my mobile so I just gave it to you now).

Comment: @fredsbend - my answer might as well be complete. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: @SSumner thanks for answering. I'm just thinking about the last part which actually affects the first part.. If we have free will then no matter how irresistible something is, someone would still have a different preference or a different will. They will not all be drawn to it. Unless we are all under some sort of hypnotism. Because of our free thinking and free will, not everyone would find glorifying God to be a happy eternity. So I thought that to be able to enjoy heaven 100% is to not have any free will. But thanks for a detailed answer!

Comment: As Ignatius notes in his answer, those who would feel differently are not the ones who are going to be in heaven to begin with. That is, everyone there will be drawn irresistibly to joy in worship, because (though they have free will), the ones who would *not* feel that way are those that are *not in heaven*

Answer (score 4):

### No, it is not possible to be unhappy in heaven

Felicity (Augustine's word for "joy of a Christian") is something which is non-circumstantial and flowers from within. This is opposed to happiness (a word related to happenstance), which is dependent on external circumstances. (This idea comes directly from Augustine's *City of God*. I do not recall the chapter)

### The people in hell are the people who would not have liked heaven to begin with

There is a relatively common saying, "the gates of hell are locked from the inside". If someone has made his life even partially about anything but the love of God, he will suffer temporary sadness at the loss but heaven is so much greater (cf. 1 Cor. 3:15). If he has made his life completely about something other than God, then spending time with God would be a punishment.

### We do not act like robots in heaven.

Rather, the choices we make (if you can call them that? Theology becomes a bit ambiguous at this point) will be freely chosen (the best source I have for *how will we act in Heaven* is how mystics have reacted to heaven. I use [*Fire Within*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898702631) as my primary source for this).

A favorite analogy of mine is that I will always choose to eat apple pie instead of dirt: this isn't because I'm not free to eat dirt, but because I realize that apple pie is so much better.

Comment: This sounds like typical theology, however, there are no sources, no scripture, and no claim for a denomination that this post represents.